# Настройка Eclipse для работы с Java 9

Tags: eclipse, ide

Не могу запустить Eclipse для Java 9. Всплывает оповещение об ошибке в конфигурационном файле *eclipse.ini*. Как исправить ошибку?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Configure_Eclipse_for_Java_9

Comment: Помогло, спасибо